# Как сделать знак системы в html?

Tags: html, css

Нужно сделать на странице систему. Пример:

[image: пример системы]

и много других.

Вставлять картинки не подходит. Как это сделать хотя бы на HTML и CSS?

Comment: вам именно систему или гораздо более сложные формулы вставлять?

Comment: будет система, а в ней уже может быть квадратное уравнение или что-то в том роде. то есть ничего прям сложного не должно быть. нужно хотя бы на 2 уравнения. в разе чего потом сам буду доделовать

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
.system {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20px calc(100% - 20px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 30px);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;

  font-family: "Cambria Math";
  font-weight: 400;
}

.s1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2; 
  font-size:  42px;
  justify-self: start;
  align-self:   center;
}
.s2 { 
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
  justify-self: start;
  align-self:   center;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.s3 { 
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3; 
  justify-self: start;
  align-self:   center;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'system'>
<div class = 's1'>{</div>
<div class = 's2'>ax<sup>2</sup> + by<sup>2</sup> = c</div>
<div class = 's3'>dx<sup>3</sup> - ey<sup>-1</sup> = f</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

```css
div {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

div::before {
  content: "{";
  float: left;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <var>x</var> &gt; <var>a</var><br>
  <var>x</var> &lt; <var>b</var>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну и за что минус?

Comment: Минус не мой, но по-моему это какое-то извращение. К тому же выглядит ужасно. Почему не взять MathJax или KaTeX? А если будет всего одна формула можно заранее отрендрить ее из LaTeX в MathML или SVG.

Comment: @eanmos, почему выглядит ужасно?

Comment: Ну, при верстке математики обычно применяют специальные математические шрифты, такая типографика единообразна и приятна глазу. В случае с решением на CSS и HTML, как минимум, сразу в глаза бросается жирность фигурной скобки. Собственно, не знаю, что тут еще можно объяснить. Для сравнения вот [рендер](https://imgur.com/a/8KD6IPa) LaTeX с той же системой.

Comment: @eanmos, ну со шрифтом можно поиграться. Зато это не картинка, а значит работает поиск. Кстати, в псевдоэлемент ведь можно картинку со скобкой загнать, а остальное оставить текстом. Наверное, на матесатическом сайте стоит какой-нибудь TeX подключать, но если надо всего пару формул, то я бы не стал.

Answer (score 3):

Как пример для нечастого использования:

```css
i {
  float: left;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

u,
span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div><i>{</i><u><span>x &gt; a</span><span>x &lt; b</span><u></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Если у Вас планируется больше парочки "формул" есть смысл использовать [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org).
Что нужно? По сути, вы просто подключаете себе пару js файлов и можете прям в текст писать формулы. Единственное что понадобится - разобраться в синтаксисе (есть хорошая [документация](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/) и полно статей напр. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Как подсказал [@qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy), конкретно необходимый вам пример будет выглядеть так:

```
\left\{ \array{ x > a \cr x < b } \right.
```

пример: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lw2sfoe/)

Comment: Только вот формула должна быть ```\left\{ \array{ x > a \cr x < b } \right.```. Вот, сравни: https://jsfiddle.net/jue9kzns/

Answer (score 2):

Точно не знаю как написать это в виде кода, однако раньше пользовался `MathJax`

Попробуйте его - http://www.mathjax.org/

Comment: Сомнительный ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy ответ-ссылка же?

Comment: @andreymal, не ссылка, потому что дано название библиотеки, которой можно воспользоваться для решения задачи. Но на мой взгляд, это из пушки по воробьям. К тому же, если не ошибаюсь, она просто делает из формулы картинку, а если формула статическая, то можно сразу положить заготовленную картинку, и не химичить со скриптами. MathJax в основном на сайтах с динамическим контентом используется, типа mathSE.